# Was I wrong in posting an answer to this question?

Tags: discussion

To the question [To use or not use portable receptacles for baptism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37180/why-are-baptist-baptisms-usually-held-at-a-baptismal-font-tub-or-at-a-natural/37182), I replied with a LDS answer, because I felt it applied. It then got deleted by moderator David Strutton. Bear with me for a second, I want to understand if I am at fault here.

The question stated asked about Baptists, and then specified:

> Baptists (individuals who believe in Believer's Baptism)

Now I wouldn't count LDS among Baptists (because the label Baptist probably implies things we don't agree with), but after looking up "Believer's baptism" on wikipedia, I felt that by *that* definition (Baptist = believes in Believer's baptism), I could take a chance and answer, since LDS:

- only baptise people by conscious choice and after profession of faith
- baptise by immersion, normally in fonts

Personally, I felt that was a good match to the question. Was I wrong?

Comment: Baptists in our context generally means the *denominations* that have taken that name rather than the general meaning of the word which you've rightly devised

Comment: People taking the name Baptist would likely not care for the LDS answer, whatever it might be. Kudos for the effort though.

Comment: @waxeagle if you think I deleted it improperly because I misunderstood the question, please feel free to un-delete the answer and delete my comment.

Comment: @kutschkem If it is any consolation, mine was also deleted and I agree with the delete. Not sure why at least two others without explicit Baptist scope were left up (the Mods have their reasons). One actually said it was non-denominational. I alerted both of them and Bye made a correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to read your dictionary, but often it's *more* important to take a look at the tags and see the context of the question.

In this case if you read the tag summary for the tag [baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptist) you'd see the following:

> The Protestant denominations characterized by the need for professing believers baptism.

This should be your first clue that an LDS answer isn't appropriate, they aren't a denomination that is *primarily* characterized by their use of believer's baptism (even if they do, lots of denominations do this, but don't use the term baptist).

So no, your answer does not fit on this question. This is *specifically* restricted to churches that take the label "Baptist" over other labels (think Southern Baptist, Reformed baptist, anabaptist etc).